# CodeBlocks project about passing arguments from pointer types

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Here is the main function:

```
int main (void){
    tProyecto proyecto; /*Proyecto a gestionar*/
    int opcion;         /*Opción del menú elegida*/

    encabezado();

    inicializarProyecto (proyecto);

    do
    {
        opcion=menu();
        switch (opcion)
        {
        case 1: altaInvestigadorEnProyecto (proyecto);
            break;
        case 2: listarProyecto (proyecto);
            break;
        case 3: asignarTareasAInvestigador (proyecto);
            break;
        case 4: borrarInvestigadorDelProyecto (proyecto);
            break;
        case 5: printf ("\nAdios. Gracias por utilizar este programa");
            break;
        default: printf ("\nNo es una opcion correcta. Por favor, introduzca un numero entre 1 y 5.");
        }
    }while (opcion!=5);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the .h file

```
typedef char tDNI[MAX_DNI];

typedef char tNombre[MAX_NOMBRE];

typedef struct {
    tNombre nombre;
    tDNI dni;
    tTareasAsignadas tareas;
} tInvestigador;

typedef struct {
    tInvestigador investigador;
    int ocupado;    /*1 ocupado, 0 no ocupado */
} tCelda;

typedef tCelda tProyecto [MAX_INVES];


/* Extern functions prototype */

extern void altaInvestigadorEnProyecto(tProyecto* proyecto);
extern void listarProyecto(tProyecto* proyecto);
extern void inicializarProyecto(tProyecto* proyecto );
extern void borrarInvestigadorDelProyecto(tProyecto* proyecto);
extern void asignarTareasAInvestigador(tProyecto* proyecto);
```

The problem in CodeBlocks words is "warning: passing argument 1 of 'inicializarProyecto' from incompatible pointer type--note: expected 'struct tCelda (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'struct tCelda *"

I understand this means that the function expects a struct array but I'm sending just a struct to it. I don't know how to design it so it works that way. The problem is on the calling of the functions in the main and in the "extern void" functions. I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me how to do it.

This are the functions where the pointer is used:

```
void altaInvestigadorEnProyecto(tProyecto* proyecto){
    tNombre nombre;
    tDNI dni;
    int salida = 0;

    if (haySitioEnProyecto(proyecto, &salida) == 1){
        printf("\nIntroduzca el investigador a dar de alta: \n");
        scanf("%s\n", nombre);
        if (strncmp(proyecto[salida]->investigador.nombre, nombre, MAX_NOMBRE) 
                != 0){
            printf("\nIntroduzca el DNI del investigador a dar de alta: \n");
            scanf("%s\n", dni);
            proyecto[salida]->ocupado = 1;
            strncpy(proyecto[salida]->investigador.nombre, nombre, MAX_NOMBRE);
            strncpy(proyecto[salida]->investigador.dni, dni, MAX_DNI);
        }
    }
}

int haySitioEnProyecto(tProyecto * proyecto, int * sitio){
    int ok = 0;
    int i;

    for (i=0; (i<MAX_INVES) && (ok == 0); i++){
        if (proyecto[i]->ocupado == 0){
            ok = 1;
            *sitio = i;
        }
    }
    return ok;
}

void listarProyecto(tProyecto * proyecto){
    int i;
    printf("/nProyecto: \n");
    for(i=0; i<MAX_INVES; i++){
        if (proyecto[i]->ocupado == 1){
            printf("/nInvestigador:\n");
            printf("/n/tNombre: %s: \n", proyecto[i]->investigador.nombre);
            printf("/n/tDNI: %s: \n", proyecto[i]->investigador.dni);
            printf("/n/tTareas:\n");
            listarTareasAsignadas(proyecto[i]->investigador.tareas);
        }
    }
}

void asignarTareasAInvestigador(tProyecto * proyecto){
    tDNI dni;
    int posicion = 0;
    int aniadir = 0;
    int i;

    listarProyecto(proyecto);
    printf("\nIntroduzca el DNI del investigador al que se quiere asignar 
tareas: \n");
    scanf("%s\n", dni);
    if (buscarInvestigadorPorDNI(proyecto, dni, &posicion) == 1){
        for (i = 0; i < (MAX_TAREAS - proyecto[posicion]-
        >investigador.tareas.numeroTareasAsignadas); i++){
            printf("/n¿Quiere aniadir una tarea?: (0: no quiero; 1: quiero)\n");
            scanf("%u\n", &aniadir);
            if (aniadir == 1){
                if (proyecto[posicion]-
                        >investigador.tareas.numeroTareasAsignadas < MAX_TAREAS){
                    aniadirTarea(&(proyecto[posicion]->investigador.tareas));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int buscarInvestigadorPorDNI(tProyecto * proyecto, tDNI dni, int * posicion)
{
    int ok = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; (i < MAX_INVES) && (ok == 0); i++){
        if (strncmp(proyecto[i]->investigador.dni, dni, MAX_DNI) == 0){
            ok = 1;
            *posicion = i;
        }
    }
    return ok;
}

void borrarInvestigadorDelProyecto(tProyecto * proyecto){
    tDNI dni;
    int posicion = 0;

    listarProyecto(proyecto);
    printf("\nIntroduzca el DNI del investigador que quiere eliminar: \n");
    scanf("%s\n", dni);
    if (buscarInvestigadorPorDNI(proyecto, dni, &posicion) == 1){
        proyecto[posicion]->ocupado = 0;
        strncpy(proyecto[posicion]->investigador.nombre, "", MAX_NOMBRE);
        strncpy(proyecto[posicion]->investigador.dni, "", MAX_DNI);
        inicializarTareasAsignadas(&(proyecto[posicion]->investigador.tareas));
    }

}
```

Comment: You should try to drill down the problem a bit and post [mcve]. And please indent the code.

Comment: For example here you could have easily omitted the other methods. That would also work towards providing a [mcve]. And indenting your code is much more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is - you have called it wrong.

```
inicializarProyecto (proyecto);
```

will be

```
inicializarProyecto (&proyecto);
```

That will solve the warning message. First one had type of `tCelda *` but the second one will be `tCelda (*)[MAX_INVES]` which in turn matches with the pointer to the typedef-ed type `tProyecto` (which is basically `tCelda [MAX_INVES]`).

That means wherever you have `tProyecto * proyecto` pass `&proyecto` and then in the functions you will access it like this

```
(*proyecto)[i].ocupado = 1;
```

or

```
proyecto[0][i].ocupado = 1;
```

where `i` is obviously `i>=0` and `i<=MAX_INVES-1`.